# How to put polymer iron form inputs within html table

Tags: html, forms, polymer, html-table

am trying to develop a basic form using polymerjs.
using iron-forms element alone i was able to create a form using the
second example in the following link reference :
https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-form?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=iron-form

but am not able to incorporate this with normal html table.

what i want to create is to make each input within the table cells seperately, similar as follows:

```
<form is="iron-form" method="get" action="/" id="submitOptions">
            <table style="width: 95%;" align= "center">
                   <tr>
                        <td style="width: 50%;text-align: left;">                           
                            <paper-input name="User Name" label="User Name" required auto-validate autofocus  style="width: 70%;" error-message="Username is required"> </paper-input>           
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50%;c">
                          <paper-input label="Employer (Optional)" style="width: 70%;"> 
                         </paper-input>
                        </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                        <td style="width: 50%;text-align: left;">                           
                            <paper-input name="password" label="Password" type="password" required char-counter maxlength="10" style="width: 70%;" auto-validate allowed-char-counter minlength="6" error-message="Must be at least 6 characters."></paper-input>
                        </td>
                   </tr>
                   <div class="card-actions">
                     <tr>
                          <td colspan="2" align="center"
                              </br> <paper-button raised onclick="_submit(event)">Submit</paper-button>      
                          </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                          <td colspan="2" align="center">
                               <paper-button raised onclick="_reset(event)">Reset</paper-button>       
                          </td>
                     </tr>
                   </div> 
                   <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center">
                          <div class="output"></div>
                        </td>
                   </tr>                    
          </table>
          </form>
```

script code:

```
<script>function _submit(event) {
Polymer.dom(event).localTarget.parentElement.submit(); }function _reset(event) {
var form = Polymer.dom(event).localTarget.parentElement
form.reset();
form.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = ''; }submitOptions.addEventListener('iron-form-submit', function(event) {
this.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(event.detail);}); </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should avoid using tables for layout purposes and use the iron-flex-layout or flexboxes themselves.

This will also help you achieve a responsive layout, i.e. a layout that will change depending on screen size.

See this question: [How do I use flexbox together with Polymer to make tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38388469/how-do-i-use-flexbox-together-with-polymer-to-make-tables?rq=1)

Guides:

- iron-flex-layout: https://elements.polymer-project.org/guides/flex-layout
- flexboxes: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Exerpt from http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_layout.asp

> "HTML Tables The  element was not designed to be a layout tool!
>   The purpose of the  element is to display tabular data. So, do
>   not use tables for your page layout! They will bring a mess into your
>   code. And imagine how hard it will be to redesign your site after a
>   couple of months.
>
> Tip: Do NOT use tables for your page layout!"

w3schools.com has got some guides on how to use bootstrap which will help you as well. I find bootstrap trickier than just using flexboxes myself so far.

So I suggest you have a read up on the alternatives and edit your question or submit a new question when you run into problems with the alternative you have gone for!

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help. now trying to do it in a different way as you suggested